# Are PSL beam equivalent to LVL

Tags: beam, renovation

I am doing a big renovation, got the blueprint done by an engineer more then a year ago, but it took a while to get the permit and i just learn today that the delay to have the big LVL beam (44') will take up to august.
If I switch to a Paralam of the same size, should this be okay?

Comment: Hello and welcome to DIY.SE! Our rules are pretty strict about using Questions, Answers and Comments as intended. When you Answer your own Question, please put the answer as an Answer. Typically you have to wait a few hours to mark it as The Answer with a green checkmark, but this lets others who have the same questions search your Question and Answer. As it stands, this Question with the Answer edited into the same section is not helpful. Please take the [tour] to find out more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer, they are equivalent and interchangeable as long as with the same grade (1.5 1.6 1.7 ect)

here some info (in french) about the two : https://cecobois.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/CECO-5600_Guide_Poutres_Colonnes_2015_WEB.pdf

See section 4.5